# Jekyll Gives Errors When I Try to Run it With Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, jekyll

I am on a Windows 10 PC and I am trying to make Jekyll run with Gulp, but when I run my default task I get the following printed out in the console:

```
$ gulp
[18:08:08] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\personal-website\gulpfile.js
[18:08:08] Starting 'sass'...
[18:08:08] Starting 'scripts'...
[18:08:08] Starting 'images'...
[18:08:08] Starting 'jade'...
[18:08:08] Starting 'jekyll-build'...
[18:08:08] Starting 'watch'...
[18:08:08] Finished 'watch' after 27 ms
[18:08:08] Finished 'scripts' after 122 ms
[18:08:08] Finished 'images' after 110 ms
[18:08:08] Finished 'jade' after 107 ms
[18:08:08] Finished 'sass' after 236 ms
Configuration file: none
            Source: C:/Users/rjcro/Desktop/personal-website
       Destination: C:/Users/rjcro/Desktop/personal-website/_site
      Generating...
jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/rjcro/Desktop/personal-website/node_modules/gulp-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/unique-stream/node_modules/through2-filter/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/doc/stream.markdown
[18:08:54] 'jekyll-build' errored after 46 s
[18:08:54] Error: 1
    at formatError (c:\Users\rjcro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (c:\Users\rjcro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:195:15)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (C:\Users\rjcro\Desktop\personal-website\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at C:\Users\rjcro\Desktop\personal-website\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (C:\Users\rjcro\Desktop\personal-website\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at ChildProcess.cb (C:\Users\rjcro\Desktop\personal-website\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

This is my Gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
del = require('del'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
cache = require('gulp-cache'),
concat = require('gulp-concat'),
imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
jade = require('gulp-jade'),
jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
cp = require('child_process');

var messages = {
    jekyllBuild: '<span style="color: grey">Running:</span> $ jekyll build'
};

/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    return cp.spawn('jekyll.bat', ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});

/**
 * Rebuild Jekyll & do page reload
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-rebuild', ['jekyll-build'], function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

/**
 * Wait for jekyll-build, then launch the Server
 */
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass', 'scripts', 'images', 'jade', 'jekyll-build'], function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dist/'
        }
    });
});

/**
 * Compile files from _scss into both _site/css (for live injecting) and site (for future jekyll builds)
 */
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('_css/main.sass')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: ['sass'],
            onError: browserSync.notify
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('_js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});

gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('_img/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 5, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/img'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});

gulp.task('jade', function() {
  return gulp.src('_templates/**/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_templates/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

/**
 * Watch scss files for changes & recompile
 * Watch html/md files, run jekyll & reload BrowserSync
 */
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('_css/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('_img/**/*'), ['images'];
    gulp.watch('_js/**/*.js'), ['scripts'];
    gulp.watch('_templates/**/*.jade'), ['jade'];
    gulp.watch(['index.html', '_templates/*.html'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
});

/**
 * Default task, running just `gulp` will compile the sass,
 * compile the jekyll site, launch BrowserSync & watch files.
 */
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

So, I've looked around quite a lot for fixes to this, I've applied the .bat on to the end of the "jekyll" in the spawn part, and the error message seems really cryptic to me. This hasn't been happening in most of the videos I've seen and such, maybe I'm missing something big but I just can't seem to see where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found out the cause, I was being silly and didn't create a config, therefore it didn't exclude any folders and was trying to build everything in my node modules etc... sorry!

Comment: Thanks! Did that exact same mistake and didn't exclude `node_modules`.

Comment: Please write your solution as an answer and mark it as correct to close the question.